# text wrapping and \DTLdisplaydb from datatool

Tags: tables, datatool

I'm trying to adjust width column of `tabular` generated by `\DTLdisplaydb` from `datatool` package [like here for `tabular` environment](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Text_wrapping_in_tables). But I didn't come up with any solution.

I tried something pretty bad:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % utf8x causes problem with accents in header columns
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\DTLloaddb{mydb}{db.csv}

\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}{8cm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}} %M is for Maximal column
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\tabular[|M|]}{\endtabular}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}\footnotesize
    %\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth} %Useless here
    \DTLdisplaydb{mydb}
    %\end{minipage}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I got the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\tabular ->\tabular 
                    [|M|] 
l.67  \DTLdisplaydb{mydb}
```

Here is a sample DB:

```
entete,entete,entete,
1,"big string paragraph with a lot of charachter like that. I don't know what to say.. blablablablablablablablablabla... ", "reblabla"
2,"text","text"
```

Surely, there is another way.

Comment: It would help to have a complete MWE (include document class and database). You can override the column specifications by redefining `\dtlstringalign`, `\dtlintalign`, `\dtlrealalign` or `\dtlcurrencyalign` depending on the data type of the column.

Comment: @Nicola Talbot: It's done. Unfortunately these command don't affect width of cells.

Comment: For these with the same issue, I found something interesting:
`
    \begin{table}\footnotesize
      \renewcommand*{\dtlstringformat}[1]{\parbox[t][4cm][l]{0.2\textwidth}{#1}}
      \DTLdisplaydb{mydb}
    \end{table}
`
Association of `\dtlstringformat` with `\parbox`.

Comment: The `\dtl`...`align` commands should affect the width of the cell if they're set to a column type that adjusts the cell width (such as `\renewcommand{\dtlstringalign}{p{2in}}` or, in your case, `\renewcommand{\dtlstringalign}{M}`).

Comment: @Nicola Talbot: +1 It works. But there are something wrong with header row (entete). They seemed misaligned: some are located on the top of cell and other  on the bottom. I don't know why. for example the first "entete" (correspond to column with intefer) is located on the top but other entete are located on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{filecontents*}{db.csv}
entete,entete,entete
1,"big string paragraph with a lot of charachter like that. I don't know what to say.. blablablablablablablablablabla... ", "reblabla"
2,"text","text"
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[keys={col1,col2,col3}]{mydb}{db.csv}

\renewcommand{\dtlstringformat}[1]{\begin{varwidth}[t]{8cm}#1\end{varwidth}}

\begin{document}

\DTLdisplaydb{mydb}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: Image of resulting table]

(The first column is right-aligned because it only contains integers.)

Comment: I am sorry for asking here, but I don't know if it is worth a question on the main site or not. If I have some raw data with column and row heasers stored in an ASCII file, and I would like to: **1-** transpose this data before displaying **2-** replace the existing headers in the ASCII file with my own. So, could you please refer me to the respective sections in the guide or should I ask a question? Thanks

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Headers can be set when you load the file, for example `\DTLloaddb[keys={col1,col2,col3},headers={Column 1,Column 2,Column 3}]`. Alternatively, after the data is loaded you can use `\DTLsetheader{mydb}{col1}{Column 1}` etc. The only way to transpose would be to iterate over all column and row indexes and use `\DTLgetvalue`. (Too complicated for a comment, so I suggest you post a question.)

Comment: Many thanks for addressing my comment. In order to be very clear about my inquiry, I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412300/2288), and I would be grateful if you could consider it.