# How to load a table from file, then transpose it and replace its headers if any?

Tags: pgfplotstable, datatool

If I have two types of databases; the first one has raw data with row and column headers, while the second one has only raw data.

I would like to get the desired output shown below through:

1- (in the first case) replacing the row and column headers with my own ones, or (in the second case) defining my own headers

2- transposing the data

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,pgfplotstable,filecontents,booktabs}

% Case 1
\begin{filecontents*}{database1.csv}
            ,col1   , col2  , col3
    row1    , 11    , 12    , 13
    row2    , 21    , 22    , 23
\end{filecontents*}

% Case 2
\begin{filecontents*}{database2.csv}
    11  , 12 , 13
    21  , 22 , 23
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    I would like the desired output for both databases to be

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{table caption}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
        \toprule
                    & First Column  & Second Column\\
        \midrule
        First Row   & 11            & 21 \\ 
        \midrule 
        Second Row  & 12            & 22 \\
        \midrule 
        Third Row   & 13            & 23 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Desired Output

[image]

Comment: Do you want a _transpose_ or a _rotation_? You say _transpose_ but show a _rotation_.  It does matter.

Comment: @William'Ike'Eisenhauer Thanks for pointing this out. I mean `transpose`, and I fix it now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tabular input by columns (i.e. transpose a table)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75793/tabular-input-by-columns-i-e-transpose-a-table)

Comment: @bmv I am afraid it is not. I need here to change the headers in the data file or defining my own. It is not just a transpose.

Comment: pgfplotstable can do a transpose.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191136/using-set-list-with-pgfplotstable?s=6|32.5915

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `datatool` package stores header information separately from the actual data. In this sense it's more like a structured query language (SQL) database or an array of arrays rather than like a spreadsheet application. When importing data from a CSV file using `\DTLloaddb` or `\DTLloadrawdb` the first row is parsed for the header information (unless the `noheader` option is used) and the remaining rows are data.

The header information provides a mapping between the column index (starting from 1) and a label that may be used as a reference. Whenever a command is used that accepts a label as a column identifier it's internally converted to the corresponding column index. The header information also includes a title for the column (used by `\DTLdisplaydb` and `\DTLdisplaylongdb`) and a type identifier (unknown, string, integer, decimal or currency).

For example, with `database1.csv`:

```
        ,col1   , col2  , col3
row1    , 11    , 12    , 13
row2    , 21    , 22    , 23
```

loaded with `\DTLloaddb{database1}{database1.csv}` then column 1 has an empty label, column 2 has the label `col1`, column 3 has the label `col2` and column 4 has the label `col3`. The row indexes correspond to the row of actual data (not the CSV file line numbers). So the entry for row 1, column 1 has the value `row1`, and the entry for row 1, column 2 has the value `11` (including spaces, since `\DTLloaddb` doesn't trim, you need [`datatooltk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk) for improved CSV parsing).

So instead of using the convenient high-level user commands, such as `\DTLdisplaydb` or `\DTLforeach`, it's possible to look-up data using the row and column index.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

% Case 1
\begin{filecontents*}{database1.csv}
            ,col1   , col2  , col3
    row1    , 11    , 12    , 13
    row2    , 21    , 22    , 23
\end{filecontents*}

% Case 2
\begin{filecontents*}{database2.csv}
    11  , 12 , 13
    21  , 22 , 23
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{database1}{database1.csv}
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{database2}{database2.csv}

\newcount\rowidx
\newcount\colidx

\newcommand{\rowthencolumn}[1]{%
  \rowidx=0\relax
  \loop % row loop
  \advance\rowidx by 1\relax
   {% column loop (needs scoping)
     \colidx=0\relax
     \loop
     \advance\colidx by 1\relax
      \ifnum\colidx>1 ,\space\fi
      \DTLgetvalue{\thisvalue}{#1}{\rowidx}{\colidx}\thisvalue
     \ifnum\colidx<\DTLcolumncount{#1}
     \repeat
   }%
   \par
  \ifnum\rowidx<\DTLrowcount{#1}
  \repeat
}

\begin{document}
\section{database1}
Iterate row then column:

\rowthencolumn{database1}

\section{database2}
Iterate row then column:

\rowthencolumn{database2}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: 1 database1 Iterate row then column: row1 , 11 , 12 , 13 row2 , 21 , 22 , 23 2 database2 Iterate row then column: 11 , 12 , 13 21 , 22 , 23]

Reversing the loop nesting will iterate over column first then row:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

% Case 1
\begin{filecontents*}{database1.csv}
            ,col1   , col2  , col3
    row1    , 11    , 12    , 13
    row2    , 21    , 22    , 23
\end{filecontents*}

% Case 2
\begin{filecontents*}{database2.csv}
    11  , 12 , 13
    21  , 22 , 23
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{database1}{database1.csv}
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{database2}{database2.csv}

\newcount\rowidx
\newcount\colidx

\newcommand{\columnthenrow}[1]{%
  \colidx=0\relax
  \loop % column loop
   \advance\colidx by 1\relax
   {% row loop (needs scoping)
     \rowidx=0\relax
     \loop
     \advance\rowidx by 1\relax
      \ifnum\rowidx>1 ,\space\fi
      \DTLgetvalue{\thisvalue}{#1}{\rowidx}{\colidx}\thisvalue
     \ifnum\rowidx<\DTLrowcount{#1}
     \repeat
   }%
   \par
  \ifnum\colidx<\DTLcolumncount{#1}
  \repeat
}

\begin{document}
\section{database1}
Iterate column then row:

\columnthenrow{database1}

\section{database2}
Iterate column then row:

\columnthenrow{database2}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: 1 database1 Iterate column then row: row1 , row2 11 , 21 12 , 22 13, 23 2 database2 Iterate column then row: 11 , 21 12 , 22 13, 23]

To skip the first column, just start the loop from the next index:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

% Case 1
\begin{filecontents*}{database1.csv}
            ,col1   , col2  , col3
    row1    , 11    , 12    , 13
    row2    , 21    , 22    , 23
\end{filecontents*}

% Case 2
\begin{filecontents*}{database2.csv}
    11  , 12 , 13
    21  , 22 , 23
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{database1}{database1.csv}
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{database2}{database2.csv}

\newcount\rowidx
\newcount\colidx

\newcommand{\columnthenrow}[2][0]{%
  \colidx=#1\relax
  \loop % column loop
  \advance\colidx by 1\relax
   {% row loop (needs scoping)
     \rowidx=0\relax
     \loop
      \advance\rowidx by 1\relax
      \ifnum\rowidx>1 ,\space\fi
      \DTLgetvalue{\thisvalue}{#2}{\rowidx}{\colidx}\thisvalue
     \ifnum\rowidx<\DTLrowcount{#2}
     \repeat
   }%
   \par
  \ifnum\colidx<\DTLcolumncount{#2}
  \repeat
}

\begin{document}
\section{database1}
Iterate column then row:

\columnthenrow[1]{database1}

\section{database2}
Iterate column then row:

\columnthenrow{database2}

\end{document}
```

The loop increments the index at the start of each iteration, so the starting point needs to be one less than the actual value. The above produces:

[image: 1 database1 Iterate column then row: 11 , 21 12 , 22 13, 23 2 database2 Iterate column then row: 11 , 21 12 , 22 13, 23]

The column loop can be replaced by `\dtlforeachkey`, which supplies not only the column index for the current iteration but also the other header information, which includes the header title:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

% Case 1
\begin{filecontents*}{database1.csv}
            ,col1   , col2  , col3
    row1    , 11    , 12    , 13
    row2    , 21    , 22    , 23
\end{filecontents*}

% Case 2
\begin{filecontents*}{database2.csv}
    11  , 12 , 13
    21  , 22 , 23
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[autokeys,headers={Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4}]
 {database1}{database1.csv}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,headers={Column 1,Column 2,Column 3}]
 {database2}{database2.csv}

\newcount\rowidx

\newcommand{\columnthenrow}[2][0]{%
  \dtlforeachkey(\thiskey,\thiscol,\thistype,\thisheader)\in#2\do
  {%
    \ifnum\thiscol>#1\relax
      % header title
      \thisheader
      % row loop 
      \rowidx=0\relax
      \loop
        \advance\rowidx by 1\relax
        ,\space
        \DTLgetvalue{\thisvalue}{#2}{\rowidx}{\thiscol}\thisvalue
      \ifnum\rowidx<\DTLrowcount{#2}
      \repeat
      \par
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\section{database1}
Iterate column then row:

\columnthenrow[1]{database1}

\section{database2}
Iterate column then row:

\columnthenrow{database2}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: 1 database1 Iterate column then row: Column 2, 11 , 21 Column 3, 12 , 22 Column 4, 13, 23 2 database2 Iterate column then row: Column 1, 11 , 21 Column 2, 12 , 22 Column 3, 13, 23]

Your custom row headers need to be added before the first loop:

```
\newcommand{\columnthenrow}[2][0]{%
  Row 1, Row 2\par
  \dtlforeachkey(\thiskey,\thiscol,\thistype,\thisheader)\in#2\do
  {%
    \ifnum\thiscol>#1\relax
      % header title
      \thisheader
      % row loop 
      \rowidx=0\relax
      \loop
        \advance\rowidx by 1\relax
        ,\space
        \DTLgetvalue{\thisvalue}{#2}{\rowidx}{\thiscol}\thisvalue
      \ifnum\rowidx<\DTLrowcount{#2}
      \repeat
      \par
    \fi
  }%
}
```

Loops and `tabular` don't mix well, so to convert this to nicely tabulated content it's best to first build the tabular code and then use it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}

% Case 1
\begin{filecontents*}{database1.csv}
            ,col1   , col2  , col3
    row1    , 11    , 12    , 13
    row2    , 21    , 22    , 23
\end{filecontents*}

% Case 2
\begin{filecontents*}{database2.csv}
    11  , 12 , 13
    21  , 22 , 23
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[autokeys,headers={Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4}]
 {database1}{database1.csv}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,headers={Column 1,Column 2,Column 3}]
 {database2}{database2.csv}

\newcount\rowidx

\newcommand{\columnthenrow}[2][0]{%
  \def\tabularcontents{\begin{tabular}{lcc}\toprule&Row 1&Row2}%
  \dtlforeachkey(\thiskey,\thiscol,\thistype,\thisheader)\in#2\do
  {%
    \ifnum\thiscol>#1\relax
      % header title
      \eappto\tabularcontents{%
        \noexpand\\\noexpand\midrule\expandonce\thisheader}%
      % row loop 
      \rowidx=0\relax
      \loop
        \advance\rowidx by 1\relax
        \DTLgetvalue{\thisvalue}{#2}{\rowidx}{\thiscol}%
        \eappto\tabularcontents{\noexpand&\expandonce\thisvalue}%
      \ifnum\rowidx<\DTLrowcount{#2}
      \repeat
    \fi
  }%
  \appto\tabularcontents{\\\bottomrule\end{tabular}}%
  \tabularcontents
}

\begin{document}
\section{database1}

\columnthenrow[1]{database1}

\section{database2}

\columnthenrow{database2}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of tabulated contents]

Comment: It's truly an informative detailed answer that needs to be read carefully. I highly appreciate the time and effort you put into delivering it.

Comment: I am sorry, but after revisiting your code, I have been trying for hours to tweak it for two other cases without success. I would like to edit your code for: **(Edit 1)** copying the data as it is with just adding or renaming row and column headers, and **(Edit 2)** just rotating the data while adding or renaming row and column headers.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I recommend you post a follow-up question with a link back to this, demonstrating your two other cases. (I'm going away for a few days but someone else may be able to answer before I get back.)

Comment: Kindly, be informed that I have asked a [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415511/2288) to this one as you recommended. Thanks